# sorting of array.can someone explain about the code below

Tags: java, sorting, bigdecimal

```
String[] x = Arrays.copyOf(s, n);
Arrays.sort(x,Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new)));        
s = x;
```

Comment: The question as it is, is too broad, we have no idea of your level of programming for example do we need to explain what an array is also?, a String?. You are better of searching in the java documentation on the different methods.

Comment: Presumably the OP wants to know about the new Java 8 funky stuff; that's how I read it. But it would be very useful if the OP clarifies.

Comment: yeah i wanted to know about :: operator

Answer (score 1):

Java version 8 got a whole lot more powerful cf. Java 7:

Assuming `s` is a `String[]`, and `n` an integer less than or equal to the number of elements in `s`:

---

```
String[] x = Arrays.copyOf(s, n);
```

Copies `n` elements of `s` to `x`.

---

`Arrays.sort(x,Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new)));`

Sorts `x` based on the `BigDecimal` representation of each element of `x`, in descending order. Note the use of `BigDecimal::new` and the operator `::` (new to Java 8) which selects *constructor* of `BigDecimal` from a `java.lang.String`.

---

`s = x;`

Sets `s` to refer to the newly sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

`String[] x = Arrays.copyOf(s, n);` - Copies n elements of s to x.

`BigDecinal::new` has a string constructor, so is similar to `string -> new BigDecinal(string)`

Next You have `Comparator` and you declare how it can be compared, and next step You declared what order must be apply in your table

If you want to understand steps, good option is extract steps to variable:

```
    String[] x = Arrays.copyOf(s, n);
    final Comparator<String> comparing = Comparator.comparing(string -> new BigDecimal(string));
    final Comparator<String> order = Collections.reverseOrder(comparing);
    Arrays.sort(x, order);
    s = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder-java.util.Comparator-), the `Collections.reverseOrder(c)`

> Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse ordering of the specified comparator.

The `Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new)` compares two `BigDecimal` (x,y) returning `-1` if `x < y`, 0 if `x==y` and 1 if `x > y`.

Therefore, `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new))` returns a comparator which returns the inverse of the natural ordering of numbers.

Your array will thus be sorted in reverse order.